# Handle Edittext in AlertDialog in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

i have a edittext in Alert Dialog.....my operation is performing well if ediitext is not empty.....i want to set focus when ediitext is empty in alertdialog ..

need help thanks in advance

i tried the following code please have a look:---

```
buynow.setOnClickListener {
                    val mBuild: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@Product_details)
                    val mView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.buynowdialog, null)



                    val titleimage=mView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.titleimage2)  as TextView
                    val imagerate=mView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagebuy) as ImageView
                    titleimage.setText(ygd)
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(res?.body()!!.data.product_images.get(0).image).into(imagerate);
                  
                  
                  val buynumber = mView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editbuy)

                  val btnSubmit =
                        mView.findViewById(R.id.btnbuynow) as Button
                    Log.e("checkid",id.toString())


                    mBuild.setView(mView)
                    val dialog: AlertDialog = mBuild.create()



                  btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                      override  fun onClick(v: View?) {
                          val value: String = buynumber.getText().toString()

                          val finalValue = value.toInt()
                         if (value.isEmpty()) {
                              Toast.makeText(
                                  applicationContext, "Data is missing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                              ).show()
                              editbuy.error = "Email required"
                              editbuy.requestFocus()

                          }
                          val token: String =
                              SharedPrefManager.getInstance(
                                  applicationContext
                              ).user.access_token.toString()
                          RetrofitClient.instancecart.buynow(token,id,finalValue)
                              .enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBaseCartAdd> {
                                  override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBaseCartAdd>, t: Throwable) {
                                      Log.d("res", "" + t)


                                  }

                                  override fun onResponse(
                                      call: Call<ResponseBaseCartAdd>,
                                      response: Response<ResponseBaseCartAdd>
                                  ) {
                                      Log.e("hi",id)
                                      var res = response
                                      Log.e("checkres",res.toString())
                                      Log.d("response check ", "" + response.body()?.status.toString())
                                      if (res.isSuccessful) {
                                          Toast.makeText(
                                              applicationContext,
                                              res.body()?.user_msg,
                                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                          ).show()
                                      dialog.dismiss()
                                          Log.d("kjsfgxhufb",response.body()?.user_msg.toString())
                                      }
                                      else{
                                          try {
                                              val jObjError =
                                                  JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                                              Toast.makeText(
                                                  applicationContext,
                                                  jObjError.getString("message")+jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                                                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                              ).show()
                                          } catch (e: Exception) {
                                              Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                              Log.e("errorrr",e.message)
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              })
                      }
                  })
                    dialog.show()
                }
```

**above code is crashing** with an error in logcat:-- `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

need help thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**`NumberFormatException`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is an Exception that might be thrown when you
> try to convert a String into a number, where that number might be an
> int , a float , or any other Java numeric type.

```
 val finalValue = value.toInt() // value is empty. That's why problem
```

Your **finalValue** is **`Empty or null`**.  You must check it.

> [**`isNotEmpty()`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/is-not-empty.html) is used to find if the String is not empty/String is
> length 0 and not null.

**DEMO**

```
    if (value.isNotEmpty()) {
    val finalValue = value.toInt()
    val token: String =SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext).user.access_token.toString()
    RetrofitClient.instancecart.buynow(token,id,finalValue)
    .....your task.....
   }
  else
  {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Data is missing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    editbuy.error = "Email required"
    editbuy.requestFocus()
    
  }
```

Comment: if i apply your method ...then im getting error at `finalValue` in code -->                  `RetrofitClient.instancecart.buynow(token,id,finalValue)`

Comment: @apj123 You need checking that your value is null or empty

Comment: `isNotEmpty()` is not enough when you try to convert `toInt()` since `value` might be "ab" and still throw `NumberFormatException`, maybe using `isDigitsOnly()` or `toIntOrNull() ?: defaultValue` is more safe

Comment: how can i access variable `finalValue` in code --> `RetrofitClient.instancecart.buynow(token,id,finalValue)` ????? because as you see it will show error...@IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @BenShmuel agree. Enhance my knowledge. Thank you

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya crashing with -->     java.lang.IllegalStateException: editbuy must not be null at line `editbuy.error = "Email required"`

Comment: @apj123 `val buynumber = mView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editbuy)` so it should be `buynumber.error = "Email required"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya can you help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868657/how-to-store-images-from-serverapi-to-room-database?noredirect=1#comment118205478_66868657